Wattpad book about a mute boy. His mother dying from cancer
I'm looking for a book on Wattpad . Its about mxmxm I think where the guy is mute and something is forgotten. He and his mom are living with his mother's friend while she is dying of cancer . The mom's son, the guy's friend came to visit and is surprised how much he has changed and the moms ask him to take care of the guy while she passes.

Possibly A monster calls by Patrick Ness. A 12 year old read me part of it.https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8621462-a-monster-calls

What the heck is mxmxm?

This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in the help center.

https://www.wattpad.com/stories/mxmxm

Maybe man by man by man, so a romantic pairing consisting of three men. Or it could be some new cult.

@Adamant - I'm not seeing anything on-topic in the question. Judith's comment (which she should turn into an answer) suggests that it might be a fantasy novel with a (symbolic? actual?) monster.

@JudithJones - You should post that as an answer

Okay I will write it as a answer.

Unfortunately, the identification of works that do not contain any sci-fi or fantasy (or related) elements is not within the scope of this community. But if you are looking to identify an on-topic work, please [edit] your question and share more details about its sci-fi or fantasy aspects so that we can better help you. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

This might be.
A Monster Calls by Patrick Ness
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8621462-a-monster-calls

An unflinching, darkly funny, and deeply moving story of a boy, his seriously ill mother, and an unexpected monstrous visitor.


At seven minutes past midnight, thirteen-year-old Conor wakes to find a monster outside his bedroom window. But it isn't the monster Conor's been expecting - he's been expecting the one from his nightmare, the nightmare he's had nearly every night since his mother started her treatments. The monster in his backyard is different. It's ancient. And wild. And it wants something from Conor. Something terrible and dangerous. It wants the truth.


From the final idea of award-winning author Siobhan Dowd - whose premature death from cancer prevented her from writing it herself - Patrick Ness has spun a haunting and darkly funny novel of mischief, loss, and monsters both real and imagined.


Some of the reviews on Goodreads suggest that there's a hint of a gay relationship between two of the characters, but I'm not convinced this is the story. I'm wondering if the version on Wattpad is a fix-up with an added Mary Sue self-insert character
